# Most intelligent way of reading some data into Python

Tags: python

The following link has some data released by the US Fed:
http://www.federalreserve.gov/monetarypolicy/fomcprojtabl20150318.htm

I copied and pasted the last table on that link to a spreadsheet in LibreOffice Calc (just to be clear, the table is called "Appropriate pace of policy firming: Midpoint of target range or target level for the federal funds rate").

Now, all I want to do is read in that table to a numpy array or a python list or something, and be able to do some basic descriptive statistics on that table. Note that the table has "empty places", many of them.

Here's what I run, after having saved the spreadsheet as fomc.csv:

```
data = []
f = open('fomc.csv', 'rt')
reader = csv.reader(f)
for row in reader:
    data.append(row)
data
```

I get weird stuff (lots of '\xc2\xa0'):

```
 [['Midpoint of target range\nor target level (Percent)',
  '2015',
  '2016',
  '2017',
  'Longer Run'],
 ['0.125', '2', '\xc2\xa0', '\xc2\xa0', '\xc2\xa0'],
 ['0.25', '', '\xc2\xa0', '\xc2\xa0', '\xc2\xa0'],
 ['0.375', '1', '1', '\xc2\xa0', '\xc2\xa0'],
 ['0.5', '', '\xc2\xa0', '\xc2\xa0', '\xc2\xa0'],
 ['0.625', '7', '\xc2\xa0', '\xc2\xa0', '\xc2\xa0'],
 ['0.75', '\xc2\xa0', '\xc2\xa0', '\xc2\xa0', '\xc2\xa0'],
 ['0.875', '3', '\xc2\xa0', '\xc2\xa0', '\xc2\xa0'],
 ['1', '\xc2\xa0', '\xc2\xa0', '\xc2\xa0', '\xc2\xa0'],
 ['1.125', '1', '1', '\xc2\xa0', '\xc2\xa0'],
 ['1.25', '\xc2\xa0', '\xc2\xa0', '\xc2\xa0', '\xc2\xa0'],
 ['1.375', '2', '\xc2\xa0', '\xc2\xa0', '\xc2\xa0'],
 ['1.5', '\xc2\xa0', '\xc2\xa0', '\xc2\xa0', '\xc2\xa0'],
 ['1.625', '1', '6', '\xc2\xa0', '\xc2\xa0'],
 ['1.75', '\xc2\xa0', '\xc2\xa0', '\xc2\xa0', '\xc2\xa0'],
 ['1.875', '\xc2\xa0', '3', '\xc2\xa0', '\xc2\xa0'],
 ['2', '\xc2\xa0', '\xc2\xa0', '1', '\xc2\xa0'],
 ['2.125', '\xc2\xa0', '1', '\xc2\xa0', '\xc2\xa0'],
 ['2.25', '\xc2\xa0', '1', '\xc2\xa0', '\xc2\xa0'],
 ['2.375', '\xc2\xa0', '\xc2\xa0', '\xc2\xa0', '\xc2\xa0'],
 ['2.5', '\xc2\xa0', '\xc2\xa0', '\xc2\xa0', '\xc2\xa0'],
 ['2.625', '\xc2\xa0', '1', '3', '\xc2\xa0'],
 ['2.75', '\xc2\xa0', '\xc2\xa0', '\xc2\xa0', '\xc2\xa0'],
 ['2.875', '\xc2\xa0', '\xc2\xa0', '2', '\xc2\xa0'],
 ['3', '\xc2\xa0', '\xc2\xa0', '\xc2\xa0', '1'],
 ['3.125', '\xc2\xa0', '\xc2\xa0', '4', '\xc2\xa0'],
 ['3.25', '\xc2\xa0', '\xc2\xa0', '\xc2\xa0', '\xc2\xa0'],
 ['3.375', '\xc2\xa0', '2', '1', '\xc2\xa0'],
 ['3.5', '\xc2\xa0', '\xc2\xa0', '\xc2\xa0', '7'],
 ['3.625', '\xc2\xa0', '\xc2\xa0', '2', '\xc2\xa0'],
 ['3.75', '\xc2\xa0', '1', '2', '6'],
 ['3.875', '\xc2\xa0', '\xc2\xa0', '1', '\xc2\xa0'],
 ['4', '\xc2\xa0', '\xc2\xa0', '1', '2'],
 ['4.125', '\xc2\xa0', '\xc2\xa0', '\xc2\xa0', '\xc2\xa0'],
 ['4.25', '\xc2\xa0', '\xc2\xa0', '\xc2\xa0', '1']]
```

So, questions:

a) is it normal to get all these '\xc2\xa0' strings?

b) should I replace them all with other values, such as ' ' or '0', using (ie, is this a smart way to do it?):

```
data = np.array([[el.replace('\xc2\xa0',' ') for el in row] for row in data])
```

c) What is the best way to turn data that should be float values but are strings, into float values? Do I need to loop over the np.array?

Just considering the first column, I would like to be able to do something like

```
data.T[0][1:] = [float(el) for el in data.T[0][1:]]
```

but this doesn't work because you can't alter a slice of an array in this manner.

Comment: I read that, and also this intro to unicode:
https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html

But I'm asking: 
a) Why do these "weird" (I know they're not weird to people who know more than I about computers) strings appear? Is it always a pain to read in such a simple table into Python?
b) What is standard procedure after you read in the table in terms of conversion of the strings into other data types like ints and floats?

Comment: What version of python are you using? The main difference of python 2 and 3 is in fact handling of unicode. Do you know which encoding you used when saving your .csv file (ascii, utf-8, etc.)?

Comment: I'm using Python 2.7 and I used UTF-8 to save my csv file.

Comment: As a practical example of why I referred to reading in data as being a pain:
The first column of the table has values from 0.125 to 4.250 in increments of 0.125. The second column has the number of people that "vote" for the corresponding value in the first column. Say I want to calculate the median value of the first column based on how many "votes" are in the second column. Here's what I am running:

Comment: data11 = [el.replace('\xc2\xa0', '0') for el in data11]

#for some reason elements 1 and 3 are simply '', and not '\xc2\xa0', so I #manually replace them with zeros:

data11[1]='0'

data11[3]='0'

data11 = [int(el) for el in data11]

Now I have the first and second columns as I want them: floats and ints, respectively. So to calculate the median:
import itertools

datachained=list(itertools.chain(*[[el]*data11[index] for index,el in enumerate(data01)]))

np.median(datachained)

#which gives 0.625

Comment: Aside: you may want to check out [`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org) for this; its read_html function comes in very handy, and it's a lot easier to deal with tabular data than it is in bare numpy.

Comment: Thanks, will look into it, that was my next step, how to read directly from the page without copy and paste.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a) Yes it is normal. You are pasting UTF8 encoded HTML content into Calc. That content includes a UTF8 encoded NO-BREAK SPACE unicode character that is used for the empty columns of the table.

```
>>> s = '\xc2\xa0'    # UTF8 encoded string
>>> s.decode('utf8')
u'\xa0'
>>> import unicodedata
>>> print unicodedata.name(s.decode('utf8'))    # decode to unicode and lookup name
NO-BREAK SPACE
```

It looks like you pasted the table into Calc using a "normal" paste. If you had instead pasted the data into Calc using "Paste Special" and selected as "Unformatted text" you would have ended up with ASCII spaces instead of non breaking spaces. Also, when saving the file, you can specify the encoding to use. Choose UTF8 or ASCII as there are not any Unicode characters in that table, so both end up the same.

b) If you decided to paste unformatted text into Calc then you can process the file like this:

```
import csv

with open('fomc.csv') as infile:
    data= []
    for row in csv.reader(infile):
        data.append([float(field.strip()) if field.strip() else None for field in row])
```

`data` will contain:

```
[[0.125, 2.0, None, None, None], [0.25, None, None, None, None], ..., [4.25, None, None, None, 1.0]]
```

I've used `None` to represent the empty columns. You could use 0 or '' as you see fit. Also, I did not copy & paste the column headers into the CSV file, so I don't have to worry about them.

c) See b) - float conversions were performed on all non-empty strings while reading the file.

Answer (score 2):

a) It is normal to get wrong characters if you don't use the same encoding to read a file as was used to write it. A file is nothing but bytes and they can be interpreted differently depending on the encoding. "Weird" symbols almost always mean you used the wrong "interpretation".

b) When opening a textfile you should always specify its encoding. Python3 forces you to do this. In Python2 you can do it like this:

```
from io import open

with open('fomc.csv', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
```

I tried your example and couldn't reproduce the same error. My list has empty strings for empty cells instead. Since you have to replace them with reasonable default values (e.g. 0) anyway, either way works.

c) You should sanitize your input from the csv complete and only then pass it to numpy.

You can always just write a function for it:

```
def sanitize_cell_content(cell_content):
    try:
        return float(cell_content)
    except ValueError:
        return 0.0

sanitized_data = [[sanitize_cell_content(el) for el in row] for row in data]
```

---

**Correction**: As nhawke pointed out, I made a mistake in assuming csv handles unicode in both Python versions. This is not the case in Python2. Even if you read the file correctly it will blow up.

The good news is, however, that csv isn't a very complicated format, so you usually don't even need `csv.reader` to use it. Reading a csv-file with unicode characters and converting it to a list of rows is as easy as

```
with open('fomc.csv', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    data = [line.split(',') for line in f.readlines()]
```

From there you can sanitize the cells and proceed as shown above.

Comment: Thank you, very clear. Above I commented that I am saving in UTF-8, now not so sure anymore. I am using LibreOffice Calc, and I just tried saving from scratch my fomc.csv, and I get this message:
"This document may contain formatting or content that cannot be saved in the currently selected file format "Text CSV". Use the default ODF file format to be sure that the document is saved correctly"
And then two options: 
Use Text CSV Format 
Use ODF Format

The first option saves the file anyway, the second option takes me back to the saving options.

Comment: I cannot help you with LibreOffice in particular. Personally I use Notepad++ to convert textfiles to utf-8 if they aren't already.

I uploaded my testfile and script as a gist, so you can try it on your system (should work with Python 2 and 3): https://gist.github.com/felixbr/ea4612639d09733d55ea

Also, if this answers your questions, you might want to mark it as accepted. :)

Comment: The Python 2 csv module does not handle unicode, consequently the code to read the CSV file as UTF8 and convert it to unicode does not help. Exception will be raised as soon as the data is accessed.

Comment: You are correct. I edited my answer to show a alternative solution for Python2.